# Do I use by, for or to in this sentence?

Tags: expressions, prepositions

The sentence is

> I shared the resource link with my colleagues so that this link would be accessible **for** all members of our team.

The word I am asking about is highlighted. Should it be *by*, *for* or *to*?

Comment: I think they both work fine.

Comment: _Accessible to [people]_ is by far the most common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

[to](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22accessible%20to%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) In almost all cases "to" is one of the prepositions that is used with "accessible" (agent).

"To" is therefore the most frequent preposition.

[by](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22accessible%20by%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)

An examination of the research for the other two shows that "by" is used differently, that is, its purpose is to enter in the construction of an adverbial expressing means or time (amongst possible other values).

- It is accessible by train.
- It should be made accessible by the end of the month.

The use as the preposition introducing an agent (the relevant preposition) is relatively rare.

- ([Institutional Self Study on Access to Programs by the ... - Page 213
  University of Virginia · 1978 ·](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Institutional_Self_Study_on_Access_to_Pr/zatIAAAAYAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22accessible+by%22&dq=%22accessible+by%22&printsec=frontcover)) .. accessible by handicapped persons.

[for](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22accessible%20for%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) The situation concerning "for" is the opposite of that for "by": in most cases "for" is the relevant preposition (introducing an agent).

Considering the relative frequency of indiscriminated  occurrences in the ngram above and what can be read in the results it is possible to conclude that in a large majority of cases "to" is used, that "for" can be used, but that it is less frequent, and that  "by", much less frequent than "for", can also be used, but is comparatively rare (compared to "for").